# Validating: problems found while running docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

When I try to build a Docker image using  `docker build -t audio:1.0.1 .`, it builds an image (with an IMAGE ID, but not the name I intended during the build) that automatically runs and stops (but does not get removed) immediately
[image]

after the build process finishes with the following last lines of output:

[image]

The image shows up, without having a TAG or being in a REPOSITORY, when I execute `docker images`:

[image]

How do I troubleshoot this to build a "normal" image?

My Docker version is 18.09.1, and I am using it on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.1

Following is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Run a system update to get it up to speed
# Then install python3 and pip3 as well as redis-server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip \
    && pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org jupyter \
    && jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension

# Create a new system user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash audio

# Change to this new user
USER audio

# Set the container working directory to the user home folder
#   WORKDIR /home/jupyter
WORKDIR /home/audio

EXPOSE 8890

# Start the jupyter notebook
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8890"]
```

Comment: The line before “Step 3/7” has a valid image ID that you can use with `docker run --rm -it b56f55265da9 sh` to get a debugging shell on the image just before the failing step.  (The fact that you didn’t make it to the last step, plus “non-zero exit code”, means the build failed.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I troubleshoot this to build a "normal" image?

You have the error right there on the screenshot. `useradd` failed to create the group because it already exists so the docker build was aborted. Note the the `audio` group is a system one so maybe you don't want to use that.

So either create a user with a different name or pass `-g audio` to the useradd command to it uses the existing group.

If you need to make the user creation conditional then you can use the `getent` command to check the user/group existence, for example:

```
# create the user if doesn't exists
RUN [ ! $(getent passwd audio) ] && echo "useradd -ms /bin/bash audio"

# create the user and use the existing group if it exists
RUN [ ! $(getent group audio) ] && echo "useradd -ms /bin/bash audio -g audio"
```

Comment: Okay, I can see how that would be erroneous. Thanks. What about the lines where it says
`- Validating: problems found:
  - require? X widgetsnbextension`
Does that part of the message not point to any problem/error?

Comment: Also, is there a way to add a conditional in this build step to create a new system user only if it does not exist?

Comment: @strangeloop, added some examples. The second one solves your error but you can combine both so it works when one of the user/group exists or not.

Comment: After:
`RUN [ ! $(getent group audio) ] && echo "useradd -ms /bin/bash audio -g audio"`
do I still need to change to this new user using `USER -g audio`, or does the above step take care of it?